# HBase java error - Expected HEADER=HBas but received HEADER=\x00\x00\x01\x0B

Tags: java, hbase, cloudera

I'm trying to connecting to a remote hbase from a java application.

The remote hbase version is 2.1.0, such as my local hbase-client.

The code is working well with another cloudera environment, the only difference is that this environment is protected with kerberos, but I get login successfull in the log.

In the RpcServer log I found "Expected HEADER=HBas but received HEADER=\x00\x00\x01\x0B from :61866".

I can't find any on internet and I don't know what to check.

Any help on what should I check?

Comment: Hi, have you resolved this issue? I am facing the same one. Thank you

Comment: @WilsonHo Yes, I'll post the answer in an hour

Comment: @WilsonHo I posted the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Online I found only old or wrong configuration.

This one is the only that worked for me:

```
org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "server1, server2, server3");
configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
configuration.set("hadoop.security.authentication","kerberos");
configuration.set("hbase.security.authentication","kerberos");
configuration.set("hbase.cluster.distributed", true);
configuration.set("hbase.rpc.protection","authentication"); // Check this on your hbase configuration
configuration.set("hbase.regionserver.kerberos.principal", "hbase/_HOST@yourdomain");
configuration.set("hbase.master.kerberos.principal","hbase/_HOST@yourdomain");
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(configuration);         
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(youruser, "src/main/resources/key.keytab");
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, but can you explain to me more why that issue happened? because I configured exactly the same but still get the error?

Comment: Actually I don't know why the issue happened. I had a different configuration, like using the hbase file configuration downloaded from the gui or another set of configuration that I found on internet. the value of hbase.rpc.protection is important and should check it on your hbase configuration.

Comment: Also you need to check the hbase-client version in your dependencies that must be compatible with your cloudera env. I changed mine from 2.1.0 to  2.1.0-cdh6.1.1